# TinyMCE - ReactJS Integration and Blobs

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am having an issue when trying to implement image uploading with the React wrapper of TinyMCE. Everything seems to work according to the Quick start guide, and to the File Picker demo [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/file-picker/) minus the following:

On the demo, when creating a blob, they are using the `tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache` function to create and add the blob info. I have noticed that this function is available within the 'editor' parameter given to the `handleEditorChange` function, passed as a prop to `onEditorChange` in the Editor component. However, the file upload callback is accessed through a separate function given the callback value is passed to it, through the `init` prop object passed onto the Editor.

So the dilemma now is, how can I access the tinymce blob cache, through the different function parameters? Has anybody got any work around to this?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong? I can use like that. But, I used at `SPA`.

> window.tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;